# C# - Iterate through form components (not controls)

Tags: c#, winforms, timer, components

My form has a number of Timer components that I am seeking to loop through at runtime. My goal is to stop all timers on the form at once.

I tried adapting some code I had to do the same thing with controls however it doesn't appear to be working.

```
foreach (var tmr in this.components.Components.OfType<Timer>())
{
    tmr.Stop();
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: _"it doesn't appear to be working"_ is not a valid problem statement.

Comment: How are the Timers created?

Comment: It compiles, no error is given. However when called, the timers do not stop.

Comment: What's `this` and what's `components`?

Comment: That works for me...  Maybe more code will help illuminate the problem?

Comment: Added in the Designer. If it would make a difference, I'd gladly create them programmatically.

Comment: Have you put a breakpoint on `tmr.Stop()` to see if it's actually called?

Comment: @AhmedKRAIEM this refers to the form and components refers to System.ComponentModel.IContainer

Comment: The code looks OK (for designer added). Use the debugger as @Pete said.

Comment: I put the breakpoint in, it gets called twice (form has two timers) however they still continue to tick. Very confusing. If all looks good, should I just focus my debugging on other areas?

Comment: Stop means don't create any new Timer messages. But any previous WM_TIMER message still in the message Queue will be processed.

Comment: @Ralf Your comment helped me find a solution. Since it solved my problem, add it as an answer and I'll select it as solution. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Ralf Timer events are not queued but indeed , a single tick could maybe be outstanding. But they should stop ticking.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Not the Event is queued but the WM_TIMER Windows Messages that actually fires the event is.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Indeed, after calling stop it appears the already queued tick event was firing which was the cause of all my problems. It was my incorrect belief in the workings of the Stop() method that lead to this issue.

Comment: To be precise only the Winforms timer behaves this way. The thread based Timers are stopped directly.

Comment: Given that information, I feel I should probably do a bit more research into which is more appropriate. I'm not sure if the thread blocking approach of threading timers is right for me. Guess we'll have to wait and see..

Comment: A simple boolean flag could solve a lot. Without any cross-threading issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stopping a Winforms Timer means that no more Timer messages (WM_TIMER) are posted to the message queue. But any previous WM_TIMER message still in the message Queue will be processed. So multiple Tick Events might be processed even after the Timer has been stopped when you have created Timer messages faster then they can be processed.

**Update:** 
Checking the source reveals that the Winforms Timer swallows WM_TIMER messages when the timer has been stopped and won't fire any Tick Events then. So this is **not** the correct answer.

Comment: No, certainly not more than 1. WM_TIMER is generated by polling timers on an empty queue (very low prio).

Comment: @HenkHolterman Actually (i've looked up the source) the Winforms Timer window proc just swallows WM_TIMER messages when stopped. So no matter how many TIMER messages might be dispatched the Timer won't fire the Tick event. What's the consensus here on deleting answers that are marked as accepted but wrong? Should I?

Comment: You can't delete it now, flag it for a mod if you really want to delete. But an edit to insert your doubt is OK too.

Comment: How can it be wrong when changing this was all it took to fix my issue? :/

Comment: @MrWednesday - then your issue was not what you thought it was. And you may still not be in the clear.